# Failed to create IXPlaceholder XCode 12

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios-simulator

I am consistently getting this error in every project (even those that were working well earlier). I am using Xcode 12, was working on a few projects that were working absolutely fine, then one fine day this error pops up and I can't seem to resolve this. Please help -

This happens when I build the app & launch it on simulator. Also, when I open the storyboard, it says 'An internal error occurred. Editing functionality may be limited'.

Details

```
Failed to create IXPlaceholder for app bundle ID in.storme.app.STORME-APP
Domain: IXErrorDomain
Code: 2
Failure Reason: Failed to create promise.
User Info: {
  FunctionName = "+[IXPlaceholder _placeholderForBundle:client:withParent:installType:metadata:error:]";
  SourceFileLine = 309;
}
```

I have tried reinstalling several times but the error will just not go away. Please help!

Comment: any fix you found finaly?

Comment: Yes, I uninstalled XCode 12 and reinstalled XCode 11.4 and it works without any issue.